# node.js express __dirname parent path get wrong

Tags: node.js

[image]

The path I want is 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\interProject\crud-oauth2\models\users.js'

but it always become

[image]

Can somebody teach my why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need to access the parent folder of what is returned by `__dirname` then you can try using this ....

```
var parentDir = path.normalize(__dirname+"/..");
```

Now you can use `parentDir` in a path to do what you want, for example ...

```
res.sendFile(parentDir+"/someFolder/"+req.body.someVariable+'/someFile.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Most developers code their JS for the browser, hence the file system separator is irrelevant (and the URL separator is always a forward-slash). But if you are working with directories ,then
Use **path** module.

```
const path = require('path');

path.basename('C:\\temp\\myfile.html');
```

// Returns: 'myfile.html'

Read more about path module [here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html).

Answer (score 0):

Inside your root folder eg  let assume your root folder is something like this `loginapp/routes/users.js`

Then Try this

```
var User = require('../models/user');
```